# Check if a column of a dataset contains a certain value and if not insert a new row

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Given the following data set:

```
df <-
data.frame (
var2kreuz  = c(rep(c("AAA"), 8), rep(c("BBB"), 8)),
cohort  = c(
  rep(c("2012/13"), 3),
  rep(c("2013/14"), 2),
  rep(c("2014/15"), 3),
  rep(c("2012/13"), 2),
  rep(c("2013/14"), 3),
  rep(c("2014/15"), 3)
),
var2use  = c(
  "negative",
  "neutral",
  "positive",
  "neutral",
  "positive",
  "negative",
  "neutral",
  "positive",
  "negative",
  "neutral",
  "negative",
  "neutral",
  "positive",
  "negative",
  "neutral",
  "positive"
),
n = round(runif(8, min = 0, max = 101))
)
```

I now want to check for each group in `var2kreuz` and each cohort in `cohort` whether there are results for the three expressions *negative*, *neutral* and *positive* in `var2use`.

If there are no results for one or more expressions for a cohort, a row is to be added to the data set, e.g. for *AAA* and cohort *2013/14* or *BBB* and cohort *2012/13*:

*AAA* in `var2kreuz`, *2013/14* in `cohort` , *negative* in `var2use` and *0* in `n` and *BBB* in `var2kreuz`, *2012/13* in `cohort` , *positive* in `var2use` and *0* in `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::complete`:

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  complete(nesting(var2kreuz, cohort), var2use,
           fill = list(n = 0))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 18 × 4
   var2kreuz cohort  var2use      n
   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
 1 AAA       2012/13 negative    75
 2 AAA       2012/13 neutral     32
 3 AAA       2012/13 positive    88
 4 AAA       2013/14 negative     0
 5 AAA       2013/14 neutral     77
 6 AAA       2013/14 positive    73
 7 AAA       2014/15 negative    11
 8 AAA       2014/15 neutral     10
 9 AAA       2014/15 positive     5
10 BBB       2012/13 negative    75
11 BBB       2012/13 neutral     32
12 BBB       2012/13 positive     0
13 BBB       2013/14 negative    88
14 BBB       2013/14 neutral     77
15 BBB       2013/14 positive    73
16 BBB       2014/15 negative    11
17 BBB       2014/15 neutral     10
18 BBB       2014/15 positive     5
```

Answer (score 1):

`merge` it with an `expand.grid`.

```
merge(df, do.call(expand.grid, lapply(df[1:3], unique)), all=TRUE)
#    var2kreuz  cohort  var2use   n
# 1        AAA 2012/13 negative  44
# 2        AAA 2012/13  neutral 101
# 3        AAA 2012/13 positive  93
# 4        AAA 2013/14 negative  NA
# 5        AAA 2013/14  neutral  19
# 6        AAA 2013/14 positive  66
# 7        AAA 2014/15 negative  66
# 8        AAA 2014/15  neutral  50
# 9        AAA 2014/15 positive  98
# 10       BBB 2012/13 negative  44
# 11       BBB 2012/13  neutral 101
# 12       BBB 2012/13 positive  NA
# 13       BBB 2013/14 negative  93
# 14       BBB 2013/14  neutral  19
# 15       BBB 2013/14 positive  66
# 16       BBB 2014/15 negative  66
# 17       BBB 2014/15  neutral  50
# 18       BBB 2014/15 positive  98
```